# Allow frame breaks in multicolumn environment

Tags: beamer, page-breaking, multicol

I want beamer to automatically split my text over multiple frames (as many as is required) while retaining the format of the specified number of multicolumns (in this case 3). I do not want to have to specify the column width that is why i have used "multicols." I found the question entitled [Allow theorem split in many frames in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50436/allow-theorem-split-in-many-frames-in-beamer) but this question is unique to the multicol environment.

```
\documentclass[gray]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Example Frame}
\begin{multicols}{3} \small\raggedright
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{multicols}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

How much of the `frame` structure do you need?

This for example more or less works

```
%\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Example Frame}
  \begin{multicols}{3}[Example Frame] 
.....
\end{multicols}
%\end{frame}
```

In that it makes something that looks like a two slide presentation with three columns on each slide and a title on the first page. But it isn't a *frame* to beamer, so its interaction with other beamer features will be different.

Comment: I need the frame structure, for example I have a table of frame titles (toc) that would be redundant if I did not retain the frame structure.

Comment: @jacob well that's why I asked how much, it's easy enough to write to a toc file (and format the title to match a real frame title) But if you wanted to fake all beamer's overlay stuff _and_ have multicolumn automatic page breaking on the same slide that would get hard very quickly.

Comment: Yes I understand but I do want both of those things. You are right, I would rather not have to "fake all beamer's overlay stuff" but that was the suggested solution for getting frame titles into the TOC so I just followed it. I am open to other solutions and would like to find a way of using multicols and allowframebreaks in the frame structure.

Comment: Is there an alternative to the frame structure?