# List of frames displayed in multicolumn

Tags: beamer

Is there a way to display the list of frames in multicolumns (2 or 3).
I use the following code from the following post [[Is there any way to produce List of frames with beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/is-there-any-way-to-produce-list-of-frames-with-beamer])

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newif\ifframeinlbf
\frameinlbftrue
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\@starttoc{lbf}}
\makeatother

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \ifframeinlbf
  \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill}% 
  \protect\hyperlink{page.\insertpagenumber}\insertframetitle\par}
  \else\fi
}
\begin{document}
\frameinlbffalse
\begin{frame}[fragile,t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{List of Frames}
\listofframes
\end{frame}
\frameinlbftrue
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 1}
frame 1
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 2}
frame 2
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 3}
frame 3
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 4}
frame 4
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 5}
frame 5
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 6}
frame 6
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 7}
frame 7
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 8}
frame 8
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 9}
frame 9
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 10}
frame 10
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 11}
frame 11
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 12}
frame 12
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 13}
frame 13
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 14}
frame 14
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 15}
frame 15
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 16}
frame 16
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 17}
frame 17
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 18}
frame 18
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 19}
frame 19
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame 20}
frame 20
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When using multicol, it does not recognize allowframebreaks option in frame definition as shown in this screen shot

[image]

Here is the code I used

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % suppress navigation bar
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newif\ifframeinlbf
\frameinlbftrue
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\@starttoc{lbf}}
\makeatother

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \ifframeinlbf
  \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill}
  \protect\hyperlink{page.\insertpagenumber}\insertframetitle\par}
  \else\fi
}
\begin{document}
\frameinlbffalse
\begin{frame}[fragile,t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{List of Frames}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\listofframes
\end{multicols}
\end{frame}
\frameinlbftrue

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 2}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 3}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 4}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 5}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 6}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 7}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 8}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 9}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 10}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 11}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 12}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 13}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 14}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 15}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 16}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 17}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 18}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 19}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 20}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 21}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 22}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 23}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 24}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 25}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 26}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 27}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 28}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 29}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 30}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 31}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 32}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 33}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 34}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 35}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 36}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 37}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 38}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 39}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 40}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 41}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 42}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 43}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 44}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 45}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 46}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 47}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 48}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 49}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 50}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 51}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 52}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 53}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 54}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 55}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 56}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 57}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 58}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 59}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 60}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 61}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 62}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 63}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 64}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 65}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 66}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 67}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 68}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 69}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{frame 70}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see the code from this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109748/36296

Comment: You don't need `hyperref` with beamer

Comment: I have some 88 frames, when I used {multicols}{3}, it generated 3 columns, the first from frame 3-20, the second 25-42, the third 47-64; and the other frames are not displayed. I compiled the document 3 times.

Comment: I used the multicol package with the code I posted, but I think that the problem is that the multicol package does not recognize the allowframebraks option in the frame definition. How can this be solved?

Comment: You can manually insert a framebreak at the desired position, see this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109795/36296

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it does not work with my code; even after replacing {toc} with {lbf}. Also it will be very difficult to do so each time I add or remove frames.

Comment: Can you include a MWE of the code you tried and which is not working?

Comment: how can I include the code in a comment

Comment: You can append it to your question.

Comment: I appended my question with my code and a screen shot of the second page of the generated list. The first page of the list is empty.

Answer (score 3):

### New answer

#### Adaptations

(in comparison to the old answer below)

- removed error by using:
  `\addtocontents{lbf}{xyz}` instead of `\addcontentsline{...}{xyz}{...}`
- problem: `multicols` does not work together with `allowframebreaks`, see:

  - [Beamer: allowframebreaks collides with columns?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120715/123129)
  - [Allow frame breaks in multicolumn environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108100/123129)
- work around:

  - use `minipage` with a width of `0.49\textwidth` instead of `multicols`
  - put up to 16 entries in one `minipage` by using an counter `lbfi`
  - the last `minipage` must be closed at the end using `\lbfend` in the last frame

    - note: `\addtocontents` can only be used together with material which is typeset (see [Beamer: allowframebreaks collides with columns?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10291/123129))

      - I couldn't get the solution there to work with `\AtEndDocument`

#### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newif\ifframeinlbf
\frameinlbftrue
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\@starttoc{lbf}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{lbfi}
\setcounter{lbfi}{0}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \ifframeinlbf%
        \ifnumequal{\value{lbfi}}{16}{%
            \setcounter{lbfi}{0}
            \addtocontents{lbf}{%
                \end{minipage}
            }%
        }{}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{lbfi}}{0}{%
            \addtocontents{lbf}{%
                \begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}%
            }%
        }{}%
        %
        \addtocontents{lbf}{%
            \protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
                \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill%
            }%
            \protect\hyperlink{page.\insertpagenumber}\insertframetitle\par%
        }%
        \stepcounter{lbfi}

    \else\fi%
}

\newcommand{\lbfend}{
    \addtocontents{lbf}{%
        \end{minipage}
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\frameinlbffalse
\begin{frame}[fragile,t,allowframebreaks]{List of Frames}
    \listofframes
\end{frame}
\frameinlbftrue

\newcounter{ct}
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 40}{%
    \begin{frame}{Frame \arabic{ct}}
        frame \arabic{ct}
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{last}
    \lbfend% this command must be in the last frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

### Original answer

- You can use package `multicol` and than the `multicols` environment.
- I used a loop to create the 20 test frames (package `forloop`)
- I removed unused packages
- (Does not work with texlive >=2022)

#### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newif\ifframeinlbf
\frameinlbftrue
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofframes{\@starttoc{lbf}}
\makeatother

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
  \ifframeinlbf
  \addcontentsline{lbf}{section}{\protect\makebox[2em][l]{%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}\insertframenumber\hfill}% 
  \protect\hyperlink{page.\insertpagenumber}\insertframetitle\par}
  \else\fi
}

\begin{document}
\frameinlbffalse
\begin{frame}[fragile,t,allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{List of Frames}
    \begin{multicols}{2} % number of columns
    \listofframes
    \end{multicols}
\end{frame}
\frameinlbftrue

\newcounter{ct}
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 21}%
{%
    \begin{frame}{Frame \arabic{ct}}
        frame \arabic{ct}
    \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: I have some 88 frames, when I used forloop with {multicols}{3}, it generated 3 columns, the first from frame 3-20, the second 25-42, the third 47-64; and the other frames are not displayed

Comment: no need to use  the forloop package. The multicol package is sufficient, but it does not recognize the allowframebreaks option in the frame definition.

Comment: I tried your code but got < Runaway argument?
{\protect \makebox [2em][l]{\protect \usebeamercolor [fg]{structure}\insertfram
enumber \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \addcontentsline was complete.> ---> What to do ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. I made a new answer, without that error.

Comment: @Hany In the new answer there will be multiple frames for "List of Frames", if necessary. `multicols` does not work together with `allowframebreaks`. The `forloop` package is of course only for the example to create many frames automatically.

Comment: Thank you, but it still does not work (maybe my system).

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. I just tested it with overleaf: the old code works until texlive 2021 (but not 2022) and the new code works also with texlive 2022.

Comment: @dexteritas Thank you for your concern ! I expect I must fix something in my system.