# Dividing a proof into several frames

Tags: beamer

I want to present a long proof in a presentation using `beamer` but don't know how to divide it into several frames without calling `\begin{proof}` - `\end{proof}` on each frame. To clarify things, what I have and don't want is something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{theorem}
        The result...
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{proof}
        Bla bla bla...
    \end{proof}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{proof}
        More bla bla bla...
    \end{proof}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{proof}
        And more bla bla bla... End of proof.
    \end{proof}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it solve your problem using the overlay specification of beamer, e.g. `\only<1>{Bla bla}`, `\only<2>{More bla bla}`, ...

Comment: Have you seen this http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50436/34618?

Comment: Overlay specification of beamer seems to be nice except that I still get the little square at the botton right corner that indicates the end of proof in every frame. I would like it to appear just on the last frame. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you really need a proof environment in a `beamer` presentation?

Comment: this is an educated guess based on the fact that `beamer` loads `amsthm`.  when you want to suppress the qed box, just before `\end{proof}`, insert `\let\qedsymbol\relax`.  if the `beamer` proof behaves the same way as `\amsthm`, this shouldn't persist past the `\end{proof}`.

Answer (score 17):

Overlay specification can be used to achieve this.

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{theorem}
        The result...
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{proof}
        \only<1>{Bla bla bla...}
        \only<2>{More bla bla bla...}
        \only<3>{And more bla bla bla... End of proof.}
    \end{proof}
\end{frame}
```

To have the qed-symbol (usually little square) only on the last frame insert

```
\alt<3>{\qedhere}{\phantom\qedhere}
```

just before `\end{proof}`.