# How to continue the proof in the next slide

Tags: beamer, proof-package, slideshow

How to continue the contents of a slide?

I want to do a beamer presentation of a proof of a theorem.

But the problem is I can't fit the proof of the theorem in a single slide as its a big proof.
Also I dont want to fit it in a single slide as it would make look things ugly.

As a result I have to write

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{proof}
\end{proof}
\end{frame}
```

for every slide.

Is it possible to write `\begin{proof} ...\end{proof}` once but just continue adding

```
\begin{frame}...\end{frame}
```

If not then what technique I should use to continue the proof on the next slide??
Please help.

Comment: Aparently, a `proof` environment can't be broken across frames (automatically). You could, however, use overlay, as shown here: [Dividing a proof into several frames](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144993/134144) or one of the approaches mentioned in the answers to [Allow theorem split in many frames in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50436/134144)