# Frame break for long proofs and theorems

Tags: beamer, theorems, size

I have succeeded in fitting my long theorem and its proof on multiple broken frames of the same environment. However I want to shrink my frames for better display.

How can I use

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
```

together with `[shrink]`?

Comment: Instead of using shrink, you can manually use a smaller font size.

Comment: I found help from other questions on this blog.

Comment: Can you please give the link to this other question?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50436/allow-theorem-split-in-many-frames-in-beamer