# How to split theorem environment into two frames?

Tags: mdframed, framed

I am using

```
\newtheorem{thm}{theorem}
\begin{frame}
\begin{thm}



\end{thm}
\end{frame}
```

but when theorem is long and frame doesn't have enough space then I used a next frame like,

```
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
```

but in the second frame theorem environment is not continue...
I need a theorem environment in both frames for long statements of my theorem for the presentation of slides.

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far. How is your question relaed to `mdframed`? What does " theorem environment is not continue" eaxctly mean?

Comment: I need to slipt a theorem environment in two slides because one slide is not enough for the statement of theorems in my presentations.

Comment: Related: [Allow theorem split in many frames in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50436/79060)

Comment: This doesn't work for me kindly suggest me the simple coding structure for this problem